# Can I run multiple Python inputs using a bash script?

Tags: python, bash

According to many people, this code should run simultaneously. All this does is run the files but it always leaves one random file waiting to receive input.

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "SCRIPT START"
echo "user = ${USER}"
cd
service nginx start
cd /var/app/scripts
python script_reset.py -1
python script_print_ticket.py 18 &
python script_reset.py 23 &
python script_balcony.py 5 1 &
python script_balcony.py 6 2 &
python script_balcony.py 13 3 &
python script_balcony.py 19 4 &
python script_balcony.py 26 5 &
```

In each python file I'm using GPIO inputs(pins from Raspberry Pi) but I suppose it's irrelevant but regardless.

```
while True:
    #Read button input status
    btn_input_state = GPIO.input(button)
```

Thanks,

Lucas

Comment: Maybe [this](https://www.maketecheasier.com/run-bash-commands-background-linux/) can help.

Comment: @EmilioVicari   I could fix my problem by using Ctrl + C after executing the script. I don't know how but it worked. Even though your article was not the answer but it gave me useful tools and some insight on what I was doing so thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Why not running this all in **one** `.py`?
For instance:

```
import script_reset, script_print_ticket, script_balcony
if __name__ == '__main__':
    script_reset.main(-1)
    while True:
        script_print_ticket.main(18)
        script_reset.main(23)
        for i, p in enumerate([5, 6, 13, 19, 26], 1):
            script_balcony.main(p,i)
        timer.sleep(1)
```

Comment: I could fix my problem by using  Ctrl + C after executing the script. I don't know how but it worked. I will check your answer anyway later this day, because it could be good for future projects. Also I was requested to do in a form that was easy to configure, with the bash script easier on the eyes, Thank you.